# How to allow login without letting them know password

Tags: windows-7, password-protection, internet-security

The auditor of our company wants to view a few of our email accounts and access our income tax page. We what to give him full access without letting him know our passwords. I want something that:

- fills login ID and password on login page automatically, but should not fill "Your Old Password" field on any other page especially not on password-change-page
- auto fill of passwords on login page should not require knowing master password, but viewing passwords in plain text should (chrome like behavior and not like lastpass or Firefox)
- the master password should be different from windows password

Comment: Does the auditor require unattended login in the first place?

Comment: @grawity we have more than one offices, so at times yes

Comment: Doesn't your system have an actual audit account or the option to setup permissions in a way that would let him view the required information? Alternatively maybe dump the information from those accounts?